# Find all possible splitting by collections of subsets in Scala

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, jvm

I got a collection of elements and all possible subsets (power set), how to find a set of splitting of the collection by different elements of power set?

Example:

```
val nums = List(1,1,2,2,3)
val combinations = {
  for {
    len <- 1 to itms.length
    comb <- itms combinations len
  } yield comb
 }.toList
```

And I need to get something like this:

```
List(List(List(1), List(1), List(2), List(2), List(3)), List(List(1),
  List(1), List(2), List(2, 3)), List(List(1), List(1), List(2, 2), List(3), ... , 
  List(List(1,1,2,2,3)))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what precisely the operation is to "split the collection by different elements of its power set"?  Suppose you have a collection `xs` and a power set element `psi`.  What is `xs` split by `psi`?  (It is not obvious because the power set elements need not be contiguous.)

Comment: @RexKerr I meant that find all possible combination of elements from `psi` which `xs` can be represented by, i.e. `xs = 112` ; `psi = 1, 2, 11, 12, 112` ; `result = {[1, 1, 2], [1, 12], [11, 2], [112]}`